# Is it possible to increase the value of a for/while/if loop JUST once while the statement is True?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

- **Python**

Is it possible to increase the value of a for/while/if loop just once while the statement is true? E.g.,

```
n = [1,2,3,4,5,-1,4,5,6,3,-1,3,4,5,-1]

counter = 0
```

Let's say I want my counter to go up JUST once while i>0 for every element in the array until false. How can I translate this into coding language so that for 1 2 3 4 5 I get True but only once for 4 5 6 3 True, so counter up again?

I'm looking for a counter of 3 since the elements are > 0 three times, if that makes sense. I'm not quite sure how to explain it.

Comment: yea your explanation wasnt great honestly.. whats the logic beind when you want it to count? you want make it only go up under a specific condition (or set of conditions) with an if-statement inside your for-loop

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense to say that I want to up the counter just once if my statement is True UNTIL it becomes false again.

Comment: so you want to iterate through the list, and increment by 1 only when the element is greater than 0?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if understand you correctly but this will only increase the counter when the element equals `-1`.

```
counter = 0
n = [1,2,3,4,5,-1,4,5,6,3,-1,3,4,5,-1]

for element in n:
    if element == -1:# increases the counter when reaching an element with value -1
        counter += 1
        continue
    print(element, True)# ? not quite sure what you mean with "i should get TRUE"
```

Comment: I think he wants it to increment when the element is greater than 0, in that case, just replace `if element == -1:` with `if element >0:`